# NoErrorObjectAvailable Script error in Salesforce lightning aura component

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lightning

Error  -

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtsW4.png)

**My code -**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome"
        access="global" controller="DisplayProductLinesController">
      
    <aura:attribute type="Product_Lineitem__c[]" name="prodList"/>
    <aura:attribute name="mycolumns" type="List"/>    
    <aura:attribute name="selectedprods" type="List" default=""/> 
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.fetchprod}"/>     
    
      
    <lightning:datatable data="{! v.prodList }"
                         columns="{! v.mycolumns }"
                         keyField="id"
                         hideCheckboxColumn="false"
                         onrowselection="{! c.getSelectedName}"/>
   
</aura:component>
```

**HELPER -**

```
({
    fetchProdHelper : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.mycolumns', [
            {label: 'Id', fieldName: 'Id', type: 'text'},
            {label: 'Prod Detail', fieldName: 'Prod_Detail__c', type: 'text'},
            {label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'}          
            ]);
        var action = component.get("c.fetchProdLines");
        action.setParams({
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.prodList", response.getReturnValue());
            }
            
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    
    getSelectedName: function (component, event) {
        var selectedRows = event.getParam('selectedRows');
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++){
            alert("You selected: " + selectedRows[i].Id);
        }
    }
    
   
})
```

Where am I going wrong?

I tried to resolve this by adding <aura:if isTrue="{!v.errorMsg}"> to display error but it did not resolve the issue.